# Understanding the output using local and global variables of same name

Tags: python, global-variables

Following is the code snippet and '#' post print statement is the output printed. I was expecting the last 'print a' to print 1 and not 3. What changed in `bar()`.

Also I got a Syntax warning:- `SyntaxWarning: name 'a' is assigned to before global declaration`

```
a = 1
def foo():
    a = 2
    print a #2

def bar():
    a = 3
    print a #3
    global a
    print a #3

foo()
print a #1
bar()
print a #3
```

Comment: http://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this problem you need to understand scoping rule of Python

[Execution model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html)

> A scope defines the visibility of a name within a block. If a local
>   variable is defined in a block, its scope includes that block. If the
>   definition occurs in a function block, the scope extends to any blocks
>   contained within the defining one, unless a contained block introduces
>   a different binding for the name.

So in your function `bar`, when you first assigned the number `3` to the variable `a`, it introduced a new local variable in the function scope, the lifetime of which extends till the end of the current scope which is the function body.

Now subsequently, you have used the `global` key word to access the global variable `a` and add it in the current local scope. This is conflicting as there cannot exist two variables with the same nomenclature in the same scope.

So ideally, you need to rename your former local declaration to a different name.

**Note** Do you have any particular use case that you need the particular mixed usage of local and global? Can you just solve it by renaming the local variable?

Comment: I do not need a fix for this. I was testing something and this came in. But I think the conflict may be dangerous if used unnoticed.